# Java hibernate get all Entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two `Java Hibernate` entities `user` and `userPick`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User{

  @Column(length=50)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany
  private List<UserPick> userPicks = new ArrayList<UserPick>(0);
  ...
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usersPicks")
public class UserPick {
  ...
  User user; // this line no exist in code 
             // I want get it when load all picks
             // I am confused here or I can do it, because in user is
             // List<userPick> and it sounds like circle
             // user.getUserPicks().getUser().getUserPicks()....  
  ...
```

When I load user everythings ok.

```
public User findByUserName(String name) {

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name",name));

    List<User> users = criteria.list();

    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

But I looking way how I can get all `usersPick's` in one list and get picks users, something like:

```
public List<UserPick> getAllPicks(){
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserPick.class);
   List<UserPick> picks = criteria.list();
   return picks;
}
```

I want to print pick user name `System.out.print(picks.get(0).getUser().getName())`

Comment: your code raise an exception ?

Comment: Problems `user.getUserPicks().getUser().getUserPicks().....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok to have an association to `User` in the `UserPick`. To associate `User` and `UserPick` by a foreign key `fk_user` in the `UserPick`, please, add `mappedBy = "user"` to `User` and make association to `User` lazy in the `UserPick`. To specify a foreign key column name you need `@JoinnColumn(name = "fk_user")`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User{

  @Column(length=50)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<UserPick> userPicks = new ArrayList<UserPick>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="usersPicks")
public class UserPick {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinnColumn(name = "fk_user") 
  private User user;

}
```

And you can fetch users by the way suggested by @StanislavL (except that you don't need to make an alias to `user`)

```
public List<UserPick> getAllPicks(){
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserPick.class)
       .setFetchMode("user", FetchMode.JOIN);
   return criteria.list();
}
```

Even if an association to `User` in `UserPick` is not lazy It is not a problem  because of Hibernate uses a cache to set the same `User` to all user's `UserPick`.

Answer (score 1):

```
criteria.setFetchMode("user", FetchMode.JOIN)
.createAlias("user", "user")
```

The FetchMode.JOIN should solve n+1 query problem

Comment: Where I should use this code in `findByUserName` or in `getAllPicks` or in both?

Comment: in the getAllPicks()